# Writing new rows into CSV

Tags: python-3.x

Im not a dedicated programmer and its my first time doing a thing like this.

I made a While loop which uses entries that would be written into a CSV file.

I dont know how to repeat the loop so new values would be written into the new rows in alphabetical order.

I managed to make this program that works, but only has a one time entry into a one single row. Every time you would restart the program and enter something new it would override the old data row in CSV.

```
import csv 

fields = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Status'] 

rows = [[]]

while True:

    status=input("Enter status number: ")
    if status !="3":
        print("Wrong status number.")
    else:
        surname=input("Enter surname: ")
        name=input("Enter name: ")
        value=surname+"-"+name+"-"+name+"."+surname+"@mail.com"+","+status
        print(value)
        value=name+","+surname+","+name+"."+surname+"@mail.com"+","+status
        for inner_row in rows:
            _name=name
            _surname=surname
            _name_surname=name+"."+surname+"@mail.com"
            rows[0].append(_name)
            rows[0].append(_surname)
            rows[0].append(_name_surname)
            rows[0].append(status)
        break

filename = "university_records.csv"

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile: 

    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 

    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Please be more exact about what you're trying to achieve! To get multiple rows from the user and write them to CSV in alphabetical order? Or keep getting a single row but append it to the CSV if it already exists?

Comment: I want multiple rows from the user inputs and to write them to CSV in alphabetical order, without reseting the program for each new input. 

So after every data entry I want to program to give a chance to enter a new entry into a new row.

Answer (score 0):

To not overwrite the data everytime you run the program, you can simply change the *w* to an *a* in the **with**-context manager:

```
with open(filename, "a") as csvfile:
```

The "w" is for *write*, the "a" is for *append*

Howver, you are writing the fields (name, surname etc) everytime you run the program as well, this you can fix with a simple if-statement. the file-object (csvfile) has a method called **tell()** which returns the position of the cursor in the file-object. If the position is 0, the file is new and you print the fields. Else you skip it

```py
    if csvfile.tell() == 0:
        csvwriter.writerow(fields)
```

I also think you are missing a field for the file to be a correct csv-file.

```
fields = ['Name', 'Surname', 'email', 'Status']
```

Hope this helped

Comment: All of the above works, although Python puts new data in every second row.

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't do that. If you update the code in your question I can review it and see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv
import os

fields = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Email', 'Status']
filename = "university_records.csv"

rows = []
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(csv_reader)  # skip header
        for row in csv_reader:
            rows.append(row)

while True:
    status = input("Enter status number (or 'exit' to exit): ")
    if status == "exit":
        break
    if status != "3":
        print("Wrong status number.")
    else:
        surname = input("Enter surname: ")
        name = input("Enter name: ")
        email = name + "." + surname + "@mail.com"
        rows.append([name, surname, email, status])

with open(filename, 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(fields)
    csv_writer.writerows(sorted(rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I had this assignment so I didn't want to 100% "cheat" as copy pasting your code. So I mixed a bit of both, up to the point where I could explain what is happening in the code.

Best regards!